# Air application - faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend

Tags: java, air, glassfish, blazeds

I have an AIR application that uses remote objects to communicate with the server. It works perfectly when the application connects to my localhost server. But as soon as I change the url to point to a remote test server, I get the following error:

```
fault.message: faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed'  
faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: 
Failed: url: 'http://remoteserver:80/app/messagebroker/amf''
fault.name: Error
fault.faultcode: Client.Error.MessageSend
fault.faultstring: Send failed
fault.faultdetail: Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP:    
Failed: url: 'http://remoteserver:80/app/messagebroker/amf'
```

What might cause this error? My local server is a glassfish 3.1, the remote one uses apache for load balancing in front of a glassfish.
When I navigate in the browser to the url of amf channel, it displays a blank page (which is fine).

I have also noticed that when I use tcp/ip monitor from eclipse, (I change the url to point to some port on localhost; tcp/ip monitor forwards the request to the remote server), the application works fine, no error occurs. Still, it appends a jsessionid to the url.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you check the server error log?

Comment: yes, there is just an error that the second instance of the cluster does not responds. I've start it and it no longer appears.

Comment: Problem fixed: my firewall was blocking adl.exe. In the access.log there were no requests received.